# BufferedReader.readline() not working as expected

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I've edited the code to explain that better.

I've got Android application, which is client and Java server. I'm trying to send info from client to server, process that information and send the result back to client.

I'm using `BufferedReader`, `InputStreamReader` and `DataOutputStream` to send and receive messages.

So my Client.java has this code:

```
      try {
            //Sending message to server
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            outToServer.writeBytes(messageString + '\n');
            outToServer.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.print(e);
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("This line is showing");
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            String res;
            System.out.println("And this line is showing");
            res=inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("But this never is");
            System.out.println("Received: " + res); //This line is never printed in console
         }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e); 
        }
```

And my Server.java has this:

```
    try{
            System.out.println("Creating InputStream");
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String message = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + message);  //correct string received           
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Creating InputStream failed");
            System.err.print(ex);
        }
        try{
            String response = "Response from server"
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            outToClient.writeBytes(response + '\n');
            outToClient.flush();
            System.out.println("Sent to client: " + response);  //correct string is showing in console
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.print("Error! " + ex);
        }
```

The thing is that my server gets the message correctly, as understandable string. It shows in console what it's sending to client and that also is understandable string.
But when I'm trying to get the message at client it does nothing.

`inFromServer.readline()` isn't throwing any exception to console and I don't know why it's not working. 
I tried `inFromServer.toString()`, and then I received something, but it definitely wasn't the string sent from server. It was something like:

```
    java.io.BufferedReader@b3d109a0
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The sending/receiving function is called from login function, which is called from `onPostExecute`. I don't know how can  do this from `doInBackground`.

Comment: '`BufferedReader.readLine()` isn't working' has only a few meanings. 1. It is throwing an `IOException`. 2. It is returning `null` unexpectedly, which in this case would mean that the peer had closed the connection unexpectedly. 3. It returns the wrong data. 4. It blocks, which means a line hasn't been sent. Which is it?

Comment: @EJP: It's perfectly common, for native speakers and particularly for ESL speakers, to say "X isn't working" when what they really mean is "I'm not getting the result I expect using X". You'll have a job on your hands if you want to correct them all... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm starting here. The correct phrase is 'not working as expected'. I left out a case: there is a bug unknown to the Java Bug Parade. The part about ESL is just a guess on your part. I don't speculate about that stuff.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the code. Thanks for correcting me - I wrote "isn't working" because I can't see any result of this line, sorry for that. And I hope now the question is more clear.

Comment: I suggest that this isn't the real code, and that there isn't a `\n` on the end of the sent message, which would explain `readLine()` blocking until the non-existent line terminator arrives, but you should redo this using `BufferedWriter` instead of `DataOutputStream` as mentioned in my answer. You should also fix this poorly structured code. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block. You should also remove the pointless irrelevancy concerning `BufferedReader.toString()` from your question.

Comment: I suggest reducing your client and server code to the absolute minimum, stand-alone code that you can -- code that actually compiles and runs (with a `main` method, etc.) so people can replicate what you're seeing and help you fix it. More: [mcve]

Comment: Apparently, the problem wasn't with **how** I tried to use readLine(), but **where**. There was exception "Network on main thread", which showed up after using `Exception` instead of `IOException`
Thanks for trying to help, anyway, I managed to rearrange the code.

Answer (score 1):

> `BufferedReader.readLine()` isn't working

Oh yes it is. Your error is in trying to convert the reader into a string, instead of using the line that was read.

Yo should remove the `ready()` test. It is pointless.

You should also use symmetrical streams. If you use `Readers`at one end you should use `Writers` at the other, such as `BufferedWriter`. Not `DataOutputStream`.

I suggest that this isn't the real code, and that there isn't a `\n` on the end of the sent message, which would explain `readLine()` blocking until the non-existent line terminator arrives, but you should redo this using `BufferedWriter` instead of `DataOutputStream` as mentioned above.

Comment: I think that's just some flailing about; a couple of lines above that, the OP does `String message = inFromServer.readLine();` followed by `System.out.println("Received: " + message);` I'm guessing the `toString` stuff later is just because that didn't work and so they were trying things. (Edit: Actually, the OP says that at the end of the question.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure what point you're making. The 'flailing about' *is* the problem, and the reason for the ridiculous claim in the title.

Comment: No, the problem is that `message` is blank. The `toString` thing is just what they tried when `message` was blank: *"inFromServer.readline() isn't throwing any exception to console and I don't know why it's not working. I tried inFromServer.toString(), and then I received something, but it definitely wasn't the string sent from server."*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The '`toString()` thing' is the motivation for the question that was asked. The statement that what was received wasn't what was sent is a fantasy, as is the claim that the API isn't working.

Comment: I'm sorry, normally you're spot-on, but let go of your initial interpretation and read the question, in detail, again. It's perfectly clear that the OP is trying to use `readLine` and not getting anything. That's the motivation fo the question. *"Your error is in trying to convert the reader into a string, instead of using the line that was read."* isn't useful. The OP **is** trying to use the line that was read. That didn't work, so they did a silly thing (`toString`), but that's not the fundamental. Fundamentally, they read a line with `readLine` and it doesn't have what they expect.

Comment: Sure, but that's a side-issue (but worth mentioning) since it returns `true` (apparently) as the code within the `if` block runs.

Comment: @EJP I tried 'toString()' just to try, but it's obviously not the solution for 'readLine()'. And yes, I know that 'ready()'  is pointless here, I just wanted to see if the scope with 'readLine()' works.
I ant to put readLine() output to string, it works on server, but not on client and I don't know why. I added the new line sign, I flushed the message.

Comment: @mazabin So please remove all the extraneous code and show us the original problem, without the XY problems and the brain salad surgery starting with the misuse of `ready()` and `toString()`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The word 'blank' does not appear in the question, nor any assertion as to what the message variable contains.

Comment: I tried `BufferedWriter outToClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                outToClient.write(response +'\n'); outToClient.flush();` with and without the '\n' at the end of message, but nothing changed.